# If $A_i$ is measurable, prove that $B=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=i}^\infty A_n$ is a measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

**Question**

> If $A_i$ is measurable, prove that
>   $$B=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=i}^\infty A_n \quad C=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=i}^\infty A_n$$
>   is a measurable set.

**Attempt**

Since a measurable set is defined on a $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets, then the countable intersection and countable union of measurable sets is also in the $\sigma$-algebra. Since all $A_i$ are measurable sets, it follows that $B$ and $C$ are also measurable sets.

I want to know if this is a valid argument. Am I missing some additional complexity to this question that demands a more involved answer?

Comment: No, that's about it. Your argument is good, but your first sentence doesn't really make sense. Maybe "Since a measurable set is defined as an element of a $\sigma$-algebra..."

Comment: For clarity's sake: $B$ consists of all points that are in infinitely many of the $A_n$, and $C$ consists of all points that are in all but a finite number of the $A_n$. Not that it's directly relevant to the problem.

Comment: Thanks, both. I will leave the mistake in the question for future readers to refer to it and then your comments.